# Trigger Infinite scroll at just before bottom

Tags: jquery

So, I am using following jquery (infinite Ajax Scroll) and below is the code:  http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/docs/overview.html

```
     //16.Infinite scroll
        var ias = jQuery.ias({
          container:  '#rhm_post_show',
          item:       '.rhmpsd_container',
          pagination: '#rh_nav_below',
          next:       '.rh_nav_next a'
        });
```

So, right now, it loads the next contents when the page is reached at the very bottom.

Is there a way to trigger the load when the page is "almost" or 80% of the page height?

Thanks!

Comment: You would have to probably look up setting sfor it, as I have never used it, or tweak their code in their .js file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really a question suitable for SO, since you rely on a particular jQuery plugin which most people will not know.

I decided to click on your link and then navigated to Options.
http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/docs/options.html

At the very bottom there is an explanation which mentions `negativeMargin`.

To me it would seem that the code I've written below would work.

```
var ias = jQuery.ias({
  container:      '#rhm_post_show',
  item:           '.rhmpsd_container',
  pagination:     '#rh_nav_below',
  next:           '.rh_nav_next a',
  negativeMargin: 250
});
```

> "Setting a negativeMargin of 250 means that IAS will start loading 250
>   pixel before the last item has scrolled into view."

Comment: knew there was something, wouldn't make sense not to package that option with it. I just had never used it.

Comment: Ah, can't believe I miss that. Thanks for the help ! =)